# Hudson Script Has Unexpected Stream Termination

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a bat script that sets up Hudson in headless mode so that Jenkins can connect & perform automatic builds.

The script has worked for 2 years. To fix a problem, IT tech changed the internet port from 100Mb/s to 1Gigb/s. Now, the script has the following error. We switched the lines back but problem persists.

I'm no sure if the line speeds was the cause of the problem. All I know is that it worked, the ports changed speeds, and now it has stopped working.

slave_launch_command.bat

```
C:\IceBoX>java -jar c:\IceBoX\slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/jenkins/computer/.../slave-agent.jnlp
Mar 20, 2013 3:31:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Hudson agent is running in headless mode.
Mar 20, 2013 3:31:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://.....goldlnk.rootlnka.net:8080/jenkins/, http://XX.XX.XX.X:8080/jenkins/]
Mar 20, 2013 3:31:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to nhnaunxlbapp005.goldlnk.rootlnka.net:35204
Mar 20, 2013 3:31:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Mar 20, 2013 3:31:59 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: unexpected stream termination
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:408)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:366)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:327)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:323)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:311)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:238)
```

Comment: Did your IT also change anything with the firewall access between the two machines ?  In your log example above, the master is trying to connect to the slave using port 35204.  The slave port is set in the master's system configuration; Jenkins uses a random port number by default, but you can fix the port in the system configuration to make the firewall setup easier.

Comment: Sorry this took a while to reply. I tried contacting him but I have given up. Do you know what network protocol Hudson uses - I'm assuming it's TCP, right? 
How do I know if the port is open or not? I don't have access to portqry tool. I also don't have access to the master computer, thus I cannot use netstat -a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to thank Gareth_Bowles because this information helped me push IT in the right direction.

When we found the slave's computer, we relized that it ran out of hard drive space. This was causing the failure to connect. We removed some old archived build history and were able to restore the system to operational.

We also updated the Jenkins configuration to remove build data after 30 days. 
Thanks again for the help!